# Слайдер/галерея для товаров с увеличением

Tags: javascript, jquery, слайдер

Доброго времени суток, необходим слайдер с возможностью перехода в режим увеличения модальным окном, тесть на странице отображается обычный слайдер который при кликах в право влево переключает слайды, а при нажатии на кнопку увеличить открывается модальное окно с увеличенным слайдером  (что-то вроде fancybox), перебрал уже много десятков галерей и слайдеров, либо они только сладят, либо только открывают модалки. Самый близкий пример того, что мне нужно, это галерея товара в ВК. В теории я представляю как это писать так как был опыт написания собственных модалок, но перед тем как тратить время, может кто-то сталкивался со свободным скриптом, с подобным функционалом?

Answer (score 2):

Доброго времени суток, лично сам использую для подобных задач. [lightSlider](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/index.html) + [lightGallery](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/) (для открытия в модальных окнах).

Подключается и настраивается достаточно просто.

Answer (score 0):

GammaGallery + незначительные изменения

https://github.com/codrops/GammaGallery